# monitoring deposit or withdraw using web3js

Tags: web3js, events

I know I can send ether to another account using `web3.eth.sendTransactions`. I also want to get confirmation when a transaction has been successfully broadcasted to the ethereum network, or when an account received ether from another account.

How can I do this with web3?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did.

```
function watchBalance() {
  var coinbase = web3.eth.coinbase;
  var originalBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(coinbase).toNumber();
  web3.eth.filter('latest').watch(function(err, result) {
    var currentBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(coinbase).toNumber();
    document.getElementById("current").innerText = web3.fromWei(currentBalance, 'ether');
  });
}
watchBalance();
```

This will print the current balance of `coinbase` into a `div`

Comment: could you explan what does web3.eth.filter('latest').watch do?